# How to parse text with type CLOB from yml?

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, text, yaml

I'm trying to parse one or two lines of text from .yml file to fill db text column. But after parsing field in db is empty. 
So, i tried few ways.First:

```
 field:
   123
   124
```

Then:

```
 field:|
   123
   124
```

And after all i wrote this:

```
 field: '123'
```

But in db with irb you see this:

```
 irb(main):006:0>Table.last.field
 => ""
```

I use Ruby1.92, gem for parsing 'syck'. When i use sqlite3 database, type of column 'field' is 'text' and all works well. So problem in oracle type 'CLOB'.
Code that i use to parse:

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML::load(File.open('config/database.yml'))[env])
  fixtures = Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fixtures', '*.{yml,csv}'))
  fixtures.each do |fixture_file|
    ActiveRecord::Fixtures.create_fixtures('fixtures', File.basename(fixture_file, '.*'))
  end
```

Comment: Show us the code you are using to try and parse this please?  as I understand YAML, the middle thing you tried, using | to denote that newlines should be preserved should have worked if I'm correctly understanding your intent

Comment: I think problem in parsing oracle type 'clob' which converts in Ruby into 'text'.

Comment: Without seeing the code that is between the YAML file and the Table object, it's pretty hard to give you any assistance.  that's probably why you have zero responses and only one upvote on the question.   You need to give people more to work with if they are to help you.